# GBP £ symbol in ASCII php file being converted to Â£ on live server (transferring with git)

Tags: php, git, utf-8, ascii

I have a piece of PHP code, which was written in notepad++ on a Windows 7 machine

The Encoding in notepad++ is set to "Encode to ANSI" (ASCII)

I am them doing this in my code:

utf8_encode("£")

so I am sure to get the utf friendly version of the £ symbol.

All works perfectly fine on the local server.

But when I push it up to my live server I'm getting all sorts of issues with utf8 encoding errors in php.

Is something in the git push/pull process corrupting this, or is it perhaps a locale setting on the live server?

Both local and live servers run ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

**Update 1**

The actual error I'm getting is

```
 invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa3'
```

(This is a Postgres SQL error)

Other difference in local and live is live is over https and local is just http (both apache)

**Update 2**

Running:

```
file -bi script.php
```

on both local and live produces:

```
text/x-php; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So it seems as if the encoding of the file is intact?

**Update 3**

Looking at the local Postgres installation it has the following settings:

```
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
```

Whereas live has:

```
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

I'm going to see if I can swap the collate types to match local and see if that helps

**Update 4**

I'm doing this, which is the ultimately resulting in the failing piece of code on live (not local)

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
$equivFinal = utf8_encode("£") . money_format('%.2n', $equivFinal);
```

**Update 5**

I'm getting closer to the issue.

On local the string is produced as

```
 Â£1.00
```

On live the string is produced as

```
 Â£ï¿½1.00
```

So for some reason the live server is adding more crap in when doing the UTF8 conversion

**Update 6**

Ok so I've pinned it down to this:

```
 setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
 Logger::getInstance(__NAMESPACE__)->info("TEST 01= " .money_format('%.2n', 1.00));
```

On local it outputs

```
 TEST 01= 1.00
```

As expected

on live it output

```
 TEST 01= ï¿½1.00
```

With the random characters added to the start, which is what is causing my utf8 issue as it's croaking on that.

Any idea why money_format would do that on one server and not another?

Comment: would it be possible to use &pound; instead of £? £ will be corrupted with certain encoding settings, &pound; will not and will render as £ in the browser

Comment: The same outputted string with the £ is used elsewhere in xsl (and specifically checked to see if a regex in analyze-string matches £). Also the database already has thousands of instances of a £ and not &pound;

Comment: as a side. I'm running xcache on the live host and not on my local host. I've disabled it on live and not able to recreate the issue again at present....May be a red herring but who knows?

Comment: ignore that, can recreate it with xcache turned off

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but the code works as expected on my local deployment, it's only when I git commit+push then git pull to the live server it produces the invalid byte sequence error.

Comment: What's the encoding of the actual file on the live server, does it change during upload, what HTTP headers are being set?

Comment: How can I check the encoding of the file on the live server? I don't think it "should" change, I'm not aware of git changing encoding?

Comment: my plan is to change the local server postgres Locale to match the live server en_US locale and see if that breaks it for the local server. I have a feeling I'm barking up the wrong tree though :(

Comment: Can you post the section of actual code that is causing the problem?  Ideally something self-contained would be good.

Comment: it's not a code issue as it works fine on one server but not on another, it's going to be a config issue somewhere.

Comment: Local server postgres now running on en.US.UTF-8 and it doesn't fail. So not that... Any one have any ideas?

Comment: something is going on in PHP on the live server I think that is causing the UTF8_encode function to not behave

Comment: @Tada.wav, "it works fine on my (broken) setup" is far from "this is right". £ is very definitely no ASCII character, you have a setup with one machine talking UTF-8 (using multibyte characters) and the other an ASCII extension (presumably Latin-1). On the Latin-1 machine the UTF-8 character will show up as a several weird signs, on the UTF-8 machine the Latin-1 character will probably result in a strrange sign and/or an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally nailed it

it's money_format

if you dont specifiy a locale or specify it incorrectly then it just does its own thing

so i was doing

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
```

and on local that meant money_format just ignored the £ from the start of the output

but on live it meant that money_format put the unicode WTF character.

doing it properly for ubuntu of

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
```

means money_format comes out with £ at the front and therefore i dont need my utf8 rubbish

**Update 1**

Better still, don't bother with setlocale and I'm just going to do this:

```
utf8_encode("£") . money_format('%!.2n', $equivFinal);
```

Which basically formats the money and excludes the symbol prefix

and then better still just use number_format and do

```
utf8_encode("£") . number_format($equivFinal, 2);
```

I've learnt something new :)

Comment: Please read my aforelinked article about encodings again, you should not be using `utf8_encode` but just save your source code in UTF-8 instead. It also would have helped if you posted earlier that the question is about a locale sensitive function, that's quite an important detail.

Comment: At the time of posting I wasn't aware it was the locale causing the issue. As the error message was complaining about UTF8 encoding, I had (wrongly) assumed it was to do with the UTF8 encoded in the document. It was actually due to the setlocale method being given the wrong data (which was then having a different effect on live and dev servers)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't save raw GBP symbol inside ASCII file.

Answer (score -1):

Never use weird characters in your source code because no matter how much they "should" work you always run into problems like this.  (You can come up with your own definition of "weird" but mine is anything you can't type in on a us-english keyboard without resorting to alt-codes.)

To get arround this restriction concatinate in the results of the chr() function. (use the following code snipit to find out the parameter you need to pass chr is 163 in this case.)

```
<?php echo(ord('£')); ?>
```

so in your case the line would read:

```
$equivFinal = chr(163) . money_format('%.2n', $equivFinal);
```

Comment: not the £ that is the issue, it's money_format that's the issue